# Apache Tiles rendering

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I am new to Apache tiles and i am trying to understand how the apache tiles are rendered?

Are each tiles rendered in parallel or it not , is there anyway to make it render in parallel.

Also are there any performance constraints in using apache tiles? I am planning to use with spring mvc framework.

Comment: Did you read basic tutorials for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you asked:

> Are each tiles rendered in parallel or it not

Tiles use a single thread to render the tiles.

> Is there anyway to make it render in parallel?

I do not know any except you try to implement and add this functionalty to tiles by your own.

> Also are there any performance constraints in using apache tiles?

No, Tiles in combination with Spring MVC is nearly as fast as Spring MVC without Tiles.

Comment: Is there any alternative for tiles which provides parallel rendering ?